# How to stream video and audio from a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: arm

A Skype video call would be a perfect solution, but I know Skype isn't designed for ARM processors.  I just need something that can stream video and audio between the Pi and another computer running Linux or Windows.  The video only needs to go FROM the Pi, but I would like audio that flows both ways.  Is there any way to do this?

I could make do with just video, if needed.

Comment: `ffmpeg` can be used to definitely stream video, and audio is also possible. I haven't done this on a Pi in a while though so maybe a google will help you find some guides on how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

[UV4L driver](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=14), on Raspberry Pi 2 now support HTML5 embedded video with very low latency.I have tested it and it works great with HD video, no more flash plugins! Gstreamer pipes, ffmpeg or CVLC!

Here are some more documentation about it, compatible with Pi1 also but with a few caveats.

Comment: UV4L supports two-way live Audio + VIdeo P2P Calls now. In particular both remote and local video can be rendered on the display attached to the Rpi. This feature includes the Jitsi Meet Web Conference plugin. Screenshot: http://www.linux-projects.org/downloads/screenshots/webrtc-twoway.png

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options on this [similar question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26675/modern-way-to-stream-h-264-from-the-raspberry-cam).
Though raspivid and cvlc is a good simple start.
Do this on the server:

```
/opt/vc/bin/raspivid -o - -t 0 2>/dev/null | /usr/bin/cvlc stream:///dev/stdin --sout "#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/}" :demux=h264 2>/dev/null >/dev/null &
```

Then from any other device point vlc at rtsp://192.168.0.153:8554/ or whatever your raspberrypi IP is.