# FFMPEG stream video and audio from USB capture

Tags: usb, streaming-video, composite-video, ffmpeg

I really need some help with using FFMPEG to stream video and audio together through RTMP .I've overclocked my raspi 2 and tried as much as I could so far.

The video streams fine but I can't hear any audio. I just hear random click sounds.Please help :

> ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -channel 1 -i /dev/video0 -f alsa -i plughw:2,0
> -r 25 -vcodec libx264 -strict experimental -acodec aac -b:a 20k -b:v 200k -aspect 4:3 -s 320x260 -ar 16000 -ab 32k -async 1 -g 6 -threads 4
> -f flv rtmp://server:1935/live/test1

Any advise on how I should change this to make it work? I am trying this from a raspberry pi 2 Model B. All I need is to successfully stream audio+video at this quality since I'm making it work through slow internet connections.

Thanks.

Also fyi, I have already seen [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15897/how-to-stream-video-and-audio-from-a-raspberry-pi) but I still need help with ffmpeg

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you're providing the wrong audio input device.

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
```

Try the different devices you have.  I assume you are using an external webcam with an attached mic if you need `plughw`.  If not, it might be another device type:

http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm.html

See PCM naming conventions